# How to edit metadata from jpg file

Tags: android, metadata, jpeg, exif

I'm trying load Exif metadata from jpg. I'm using ExifInterface class.
But when I'm trying get some tag e.g. ImageWidth or ImageLength I get 0 or null.

My method to getting metadata from jpg:

```
String ReadExif(String file){
    String exif="Exif: " + file;
    try {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(file);

        exif += "\nIMAGE_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH);
        exif += "\nIMAGE_WIDTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH);
        exif += "\n DATETIME: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
        exif += "\n TAG_MAKE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);
        exif += "\n TAG_MODEL: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);
        exif += "\n TAG_ORIENTATION: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        exif += "\n TAG_WHITE_BALANCE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE);
        exif += "\n TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH);
        exif += "\n TAG_FLASH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH);
        exif += "\nGPS related:";
        exif += "\n TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
        exif += "\n TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP);
        exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
        exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
        exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
        exif += "\n TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "finished",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return exif;
}
```

And my method call:

```
textView.setText(ReadExif("/Storage/sdcard0/file.jpg"));
```

I don't know what I make wrong. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are hardcoding a path. **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. Use methods on `Context` (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`) or `Environment` (e.g., `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`) instead of hard-coding root paths.

Second, you are most likely hardcoding the wrong path, as I have yet to see a device with a capital letter in a root directory (e.g., `Storage`).

Comment: Thanks for help but now I have a next issue. When I try add new metadata tag to file I can only add "UserComment"
exif.setAttribute("UserComment", tag.toString());
 when I try add different e.g.
exif.setAttribute("AnotherTag", tag.toString());
it doesn't set it.

Comment: @EriiAsari: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you show the code where you are trying to manipulate the EXIF tags. Also, if you are using `android.media.ExifInterface`, you may wish to examine [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/ExifInterface.java) to see if it gives you any clues.